# ValueError: received does not contain valid XML: Killed

Tags: androidviewclient

When I try to dump my device or execute Culebra GUI, it appears the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/Scripts/dump", line 4, in 
**import**('pkg_resources').run_script('androidviewclient==20.0.0b6', 'dump')
File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_*init*_.py", line 666, in run_script
self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_*init*_.py", line 1462, in run_script
exec(code, namespace, namespace)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\androidviewclient-20.0.0b6-py2.7.egg\EGG-INFO\scripts\dump", line 221, in 
vc.dump(window=options[WINDOW])
File "C:\Users\FAMIL\Downloads\AndroidViewClient-master\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 3522, in dump
self.setViewsFromUiAutomatorDump(received)
File "C:\Users\FAMIL\Downloads\AndroidViewClient-master\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 3105, in setViewsFromUiAutomatorDump
self.__parseTreeFromUiAutomatorDump(received)
File "C:\Users\FAMIL\Downloads\AndroidViewClient-master\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 3322, in __parseTreeFromUiAutomatorDump
raise ValueError("received does not contain valid XML: " + receivedXml)
ValueError: received does not contain valid XML: Killed

I don't know what problem could it be.

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) uses `uiautomator dump` by default to obtain the view tree.

Try

```
adb shell
$ uiautomator dump
```

and check if it is working.

There are some cases where it doesn't work.

In such cases, the alternative is to use [CulebraTester2-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public#androidviewclient), which provides an alternative back-end.

Comment: executing `uiautomator dump` I get the response `Killed`. What kind of response is expected ?

Comment: https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/issues/181 you may find it useful